# Can't build MariaDB on OSX

Tags: macos, build, mariadb, macports

I'm trying to build MariaDB on the latest OSX with trace enabled but it keeps failing. First, it can't find lz4:

```
[ 95%] Building CXX object storage/spider/CMakeFiles/spider.dir/hs_client/socket.cpp.o
ld: library not found for -llz4
[ 95%] Built target simple_password_check
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[2]: *** [storage/mroonga/CMakeFiles/mroonga.dir/build.make:702: storage/mroonga/ha_mroonga.so] Error 1
[ 95%] Building CXX object storage/spider/CMakeFiles/spider.dir/hs_client/string_util.cpp.o
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4031: storage/mroonga/CMakeFiles/mroonga.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Then it fails on an install step:

```
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/liblzma.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "liblzma.la" && ln -s "../liblzma.la" "liblzma.la" )
[ 95%] Performing install step for 'build_lzma'
Making install in api
/bin/sh: /Users/ruihpacheco/Desktop/server/storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/xz/src/build_lzma/build-aux/install-sh: Permission denied
gmake[5]: *** [Makefile:292: install-nobase_includeHEADERS] Error 126
gmake[4]: *** [Makefile:409: install-am] Error 2
gmake[3]: *** [Makefile:1391: install-recursive] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/CMakeFiles/build_lzma.dir/build.make:75: storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/xz/src/build_lzma-stamp/build_lzma-install] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6161: storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/CMakeFiles/build_lzma.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:161: all] Error 2
```

I've installed lz4 from macports and used the command `sudo ./BUILD/compile-pentium64-debug-max` to build the library.

Comment: why are you doing ./BUILD/compile-pentium64-debug-max ? I do not think it is documented anywhere, and I'm not aware of anyone except single user of this script by now. a normal way to build is  cmake . && make

Comment: I'm following the docs. Doing it your way fails on lz4, exact same error.

Comment: disable building spider (by passing -DPLUGIN_SPIDER=NO to cmake), file a bug. You cannot disable building spider with that script, can you :)?

Comment: also disable TOKUDB, the most efficient (and undocumented, but obvious when you look into https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.1/storage/tokudb/CMakeLists.txt#L15) way to do that is passing -DTOKUDB_OK=0 to cmake. Basically y, you can disable all these buggy engines  untli done. If you do not want any plugins, there is a wonderful but also undocumented -DWITHOUT_DYNAMIC_PLUGINS=1 option you can pass.

Comment: Do you need a development version specifically, or is there some other reason why you don't just install the `mariadb-10.1-server` or `mariadb-10.0-server` ports from MacPorts? As for the error, you probably need to add `/opt/local/include` to the include path and `/opt/local/lib` to the library search path. Try `cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/local;/"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to build was with the undocumented option `-DWITHOUT_DYNAMIC_PLUGINS=1`. I did try everything that was suggested in the comments.